# Apache reverse proxy resolves localhost

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy

I have a webserver with dockerized nuget service running. Webserver also has apache2, working as reverse proxy, resending requests to service.
I can access web interface of my service, but when I am trying to push packages, apparently, nuget receives localhost as IP of service:

```
nuget.exe push -Source http://mynuget.server/v3/index.json .\mypackage.nupkg
Please provide credentials for: http://mynuget.server/v3/index.json
UserName: username
Password: ************
Pushing mypackage.nupkg to 'http://127.0.0.1:555/api/v2/package'...
PUT http://127.0.0.1:555/api/v2/package/
```

My apache configured as reverse proxy as followed:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.50:80>
  ServerName mynuget.server

  <Location />
    Order deny,allow
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Restricted content"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </Location>

  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:555/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:555/

</VirtualHost>
```

Of cource, `mynuget.server` is a valid domain name that is resolved to a valid ip address

I Think, I forgot to do something, but I can't figure what. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a stupid error. I forgot the `ProxyPreserveHost` option. While set to `On` it will substitute host address to all responses.